# Nested flexbox not working in Safari 10.1.2

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I have some nested flexbox layouts which work perfectly in Chrome & Safari 11+, but behaves incorrectly in Safari 10.1.2

In Chrome - it looks as expected:

[Chrome behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Pa1.jpg)

However in Safari 10.1.2:

[Safari behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDPyc.jpg)

Could someone help me figure out how to fix? Thanks!

Here's my (slightly simplified) HTML:

```
<div class="content-canvas">
    <div class="horizontal-section" id="blog">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
        <div id="divRss">
            <ul class="feedEkList">
                <li>
                    <div class="itemTitle"><a href="#</a></div>
                    <div class="itemDate">10/16/2017</div>
                    <div class="itemContent">Some text</div>
               </li>
               <li>
                   As above
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="##" target="_blank">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-section" id="upcoming">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.content-canvas {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
    -moz-flex-grow: 2;
    -ms-flex-grow: 2;
    -o-flex-grow: 2;
    flex-grow: 2;
}

#blog,
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    -o-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }

#divRss,
{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
    -moz-flex-grow: 2;
    -ms-flex-grow: 2;
    -o-flex-grow: 2;
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.feedEkList,
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
    -o-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.feedEkList li,
 {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-grow: 1;
    -o-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: First off, you have an orphan comma in several rules, remove those.

Comment: If you remove `height: 0` from the `#divRss` and add `display: flex` to it, and then also remove `height: 100%` from the `.feedEkList` rule it should work...

Comment: ...and remove `height: 0` from `.feedEkList li` as well

Comment: If you want more help, make a minimal working code snippet so we can actual see the issue you encounter, as the now posted code fragment does not render anything close to what is shown in the images

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want to accept it as an answer, let me know and I post one for you.

Answer (score 5):

I personally had a problem on Safari when the content of my upper flexbox was more than 100% of its height, in which case the nested flexbox had its height shrunk to 1px.

I fixed it by setting `flexbox-shrink: 0` on nested flexbox.

Comment: its `flex-shrink: 0;` worked great for me, thx!

Comment: I am glad it helped :)